# ¿ Como poder dividir la sesión de cookies de una pestaña de las otra?

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome, cookies, extensión-google-chrome

**Hola**

Estoy en el desarrollo de una **extensión** para **Google Chrome** y requiero de poder cargar una web en una pestaña pero separar la sesión o la carga de **cookies** de esta, es decir aislar cada pestaña una de la otra. Un ejemplo de lo que busco es una extensión ya creada llamada **SessionBOX** que permite crear sesiones o perfiles diferente pero todo desde la ventana principal, solo que en diferentes pestañas.

Mi **código** extraído de un [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/) :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      d = document;

      var f = d.createElement('form');
      f.action = 'http://mi-web?bm';
      f.method = 'post';
      var i = d.createElement('input');
      i.type = 'hidden';
      i.name = 'url';
      i.value = tab.url;
      f.appendChild(i);
      d.body.appendChild(f);
      f.submit();
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```

Este código me permite poder cargar una web en la pestaña actual. Pero solo me falta **aislar** las **cookies** o **separar** esta pestaña como si fuese una **sesión** o **perfil**. Esta es mi primera extensión y **agradezco su guía**.

Comment: Creo que necesitas usar el [api de cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions)

Comment: No tengo experiencia con extensiones de chrome pero creo que no se puede te dejo un link donde lo explica https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/why-dont-browsers-restrict-cookies-per-tab-to-combat-csrf-attacks Por otro lado la solución que he implementado yo algunas veces es hacer una cookie maestra que indica el nombre de las cookies de cada cookie de navegador. otra opción seria almacenar un json con la información de todos los navegadores y cookies que utilices para así solo utilizar una cookie Espero que te sirva.